# Identify slow query without slow query logs in mysql server

Tags: mysql, performance, slow-log

I am wondering is there any other way to to check our slow queries without logging slow query. Suppose, I have a highily busy server can't afford to log much to save memory and I/Os. Then, is there any other way available to check if I have a slow query? I know, we can do profiling of the query but still not sure what exactly to do to identify which query is the one taking most of the time and memory.

Just started mysql administration and not sure how to handle this. Any guidance will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You can enable slow query log for 5-10 minutes. Check the logged queries. Correct them (rewrite, indexes, etc). Update application. Rerun until you have no slow queries or performance is good enough. All these steps could/should be first done in a test environament of course, without affecting your production.

Comment: Thanks for the update. But is there no way available to do this without log?

Comment: Astha: There are other tools which allow you to do this without the slow-query log, but I believe they are all outside the base MySQL packages. Look at Percona Toolkit (as Rolando says below), MySQL Enterprise, and MySQL Workbench (a desktop client). Most of these tools work best with MySQL 5.5 and above, and MySQL 5.6 introduces more features which allow better performance monitoring. I'm upgrading all of our databases to 5.6 because I like the new [Performance Schema](https://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/whats-new-in-mysql-5.6.html#performance_schema).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you do not want to enable the slow query log at all, I have a suggestion

You can use [pt-query-digest](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.1/pt-query-digest.html) over an interval of time.

I have suggested this a few times in the DBA StackExchange

- `Nov 24, 2011` : [MySQL general query log performance effects](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8359/mysql-general-query-log-performance-effects/8382#8382)
- `Apr 24, 2012` : [Investigate peak in MySQL throughput](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16950/investigate-peak-in-mysql-throughput/16964#16964)
- `Jul 26, 2012` : [What is running right now?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/21569/what-is-running-right-now/21572#21572)

If you look at my [`Nov 24, 2011` link](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8359/mysql-general-query-log-performance-effects/8382#8382), I provided a shell script you can crontab to launch [pt-query-digest](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.1/pt-query-digest.html).

## GIVE IT A TRY !!!

Comment: Why are you shouting?

Comment: @surfmuggle I am just enthusiastic !!!

Answer (score 9):

You can run the following statement in a loop in a script that triggers the statement every 10 seconds for example.

`mysql -e 'SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST where time>10 and command<>"Sleep"'`

You can customize it to give you more or less info depending on the query you issue.

```
mysql> desc INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST;
+---------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field         | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| ID            | bigint(21) unsigned | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| USER          | varchar(16)         | NO   |     |         |       |
| HOST          | varchar(64)         | NO   |     |         |       |
| DB            | varchar(64)         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| COMMAND       | varchar(16)         | NO   |     |         |       |
| TIME          | int(7)              | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| STATE         | varchar(64)         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| INFO          | longtext            | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| TIME_MS       | bigint(21)          | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| ROWS_SENT     | bigint(21) unsigned | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| ROWS_EXAMINED | bigint(21) unsigned | NO   |     | 0       |       |
+---------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
11 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

In order not to save the same query many times, you may use the hash of the query as a unique key.